# IEnumerable<T> does not reflect changes on elements

Tags: c#, .net-core, ienumerable

I am having troubles with IEnumerable. `_entities` is IQueryable from EF Core DbContext. `_result` is IEnumerable.

This code does not work; _result remains unsorted.

```
var _result = _entities.Select(s => this.IMapper.Map<Models.role, DTO.role>(s));

foreach (var _role in _result)
{
    _role.permissions = _role.permissions.OrderBy(o => o.module).ThenBy(o => o.feature).ToArray();
}

return _result;
```

This code does work; _result is sorted.

```
var _result = _entities.Select(s => this.IMapper.Map<Models.role, DTO.role>(s)).ToArray();

foreach (var _role in _result)
{
    _role.permissions = _role.permissions.OrderBy(o => o.module).ThenBy(o => o.feature).ToArray();
}

return _result;
```

Can anyone explain?

Comment: You say that _result remains unsorted, yet you don't have any code that sorts _result.  You are sorting another list inside the _result list, is this what you mean?

Comment: @Justin: Indeed. My bad, unclear post. _result's property `permission` remains unsorted.

Comment: `IEnumerable` is a cornerstone interface, but it's best to think of `IEnumerable`s as *projections* of a collection, rather than collections themselves.  If you want to somehow mutate the collection or its items, consider first transforming the projection to a collection type (list, etc.)

Comment: Aside: You might be better off putting this code into the Mapper itself so that every mapping to a DTO.role comes with sorted permissions. That would also solve your issue of the Enumerable being evaluated twice (or more).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that LINQ evaluates the `Select` on the iteration of the `IEnumerable` and on EACH iteration of the `IEnumerable`.

This means that if you perform changes on the items returned from the `Select` those object will be thrown away, and on the next iteration, you will bet a new object with the original data.

Putting `ToArray` will cause the result of `Select` to be stored in a collection, so changes you perform on the objects will work as expected.

To demonstrate this behavior you can see the output if you add some `Console.WriteLine`:

```
class Item
{
    public int Value { get; set; }
    static int id = 0;
    public int Id { get; } = id++; // generate next id every time
}
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var range = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 }
        .Select(i => new Item { Value = i });

    foreach (var item in range)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item.Value + "- id:" + item.Id);
        // Will output 
        //1- id:0
        //2- id:1
        //3- id:2
    }
    foreach (var item in range)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item.Value + "- id:" + item.Id);
        // Will output 
        //1- id:3
        //2- id:4
        //3- id:5
    }
}
```

Comment: So it is a combination of IEnumerable AND Select or default behaviour of IEnumerable?

Comment: @Luke1988 IEnumerable just describes how you can iterate, how the items in the iteration are built is up to the implementation of IEnumerable. `Select` is lazy and creates objects when needed and does not keep any objects in memory. If you iterate over a list the behavior is different since that iteration returns the same objects every time